# Connecting to a Database through a separate form C#

Tags: c#, database

I'm creating a program that links to a database. On the main form when the user clicks a button 'Connect to Database', another form loads for the user to input the log-in details (server to connect to, username, and password). However, the connection isn't working for some reason. The error given is "Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized."

Here is my code so far:

```
public void connectDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DatabaseConnection dbConn = new DatabaseConnection();

        if (dbConn.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder connection = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            connection.DataSource = DatabaseConnection.dbNameText;
            connection.UserID = DatabaseConnection.usernameText;
            connection.Password = DatabaseConnection.passwordText;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection.ToString());
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select name FROM sys.databases;"))
            {


                try
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    sda.SelectCommand = command;
                    DataTable table = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(table);
                    BindingSource source = new BindingSource();

                    source.DataSource = table;
                    dataGridDataBase.DataSource = source;
                    sda.Update(table);

                    this.dataGridDataBase.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill; //showing data onto the data grid view
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Above is the code in the master class; the main form. Below is the code in the log-in form.

```
public partial class DatabaseConnection : Form
{

    public static string dbNameText;
    public static string usernameText;
    public static string passwordText;
    public bool buttonClicked = false;


    public DatabaseConnection()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        password.PasswordChar = '•';
    }

    public void connectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonClicked = true;
        dbNameText = dbName.Text;
        usernameText = username.Text;
        passwordText = password.Text;


    }
}
```

Any ideas, help, or solutions please?

Comment: by "isn't working", what do you mean?  Is it throwing an exception (what line?)?  Have you checked those connection details directly against the database?

Comment: The error it throws back is "Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized."

And yes the details do work. Previously I had hard-coded them in, but then decided to make a form to be able to connect to other servers/databases.

Comment: "Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized." - how much clearer do you expect the error message to be? You never set `command.Connection`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give connection to the command:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select name FROM sys.databases;", con))
{
  ...
}
```